# Library for sending HTTP requests in file-like objects

Tags: python, http, python-2.7

I'm currently using Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for HTTP requests, but due to limitations in the API, I'm unable to keep using the library.

I need a library which will allow me to write the request body in a streaming file-like fashion, as the data which I'll be sending won't all be immediately available, plus I'd like to save as much memory as possible when making a request. Is there an easy-to-use library which will allow me to send a PUT request like this:

```
request = HTTPRequest()
request.headers['content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
# etc
request.connect()

# send body
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(64 * 1024)
        request.body.write(chunk)
        if not len(chunk) == 64 * 1024:
            break

# finish
request.close()
```

More specifically, I have one thread to work with. Using this thread, I receive callbacks as I receive a stream over the network. Essentially, those callbacks look like this:

```
class MyListener(Listener):
    def on_stream_start(stream_name):
        pass

    def on_stream_chunk(chunk):
        pass

    def on_stream_end(total_size):
        pass
```

I need to essentially create my upload request in the `on_stream_start` method, upload chunks in the `on_stream_chunk` method, then finish the upload in the `on_stream_end` method. Thus, I need a library which supports a method like `write(chunk)` to be able to do something similar to the following:

```
class MyListener(Listener):
    request = None

    def on_stream_start(stream_name):
        request = RequestObject(get_url(), "PUT")
        request.headers.content_type = "application/octet-stream"
        # ...

    def on_stream_chunk(chunk):
        request.write_body(chunk + sha256(chunk).hexdigest())

    def on_stream_end(total_size):
        request.close()
```

The `requests` library supports file-like objects and generators for *reading* but nothing for *writing* out the requests: pull instead of push. Is there a library which will allow me to push data up the line to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell `httplib`'s [`HTTPConnection.request`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httpconnection-objects) does exactly what you want.

I tracked down the function which actually does the sending, and as long as you're passing a file-like object (and not a string), it chunks it up:

```
Definition: httplib.HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
Source:

def send(self, data):
    """Send `data' to the server."""
    if self.sock is None:
        if self.auto_open:
            self.connect()
        else:
            raise NotConnected()

    if self.debuglevel > 0:
        print "send:", repr(data)
    blocksize = 8192
    if hasattr(data,'read') and not isinstance(data, array):
        if self.debuglevel > 0: print "sendIng a read()able"

        ## {{{ HERE IS THE CHUCKING LOGIC
        datablock = data.read(blocksize)
        while datablock:
            self.sock.sendall(datablock)
            datablock = data.read(blocksize)
        ## }}}

    else:
        self.sock.sendall(data)
```

Comment: I've just updated the question with a better example of my use-case. Please let me know if your solution would still apply with the updated question/example.

Answer (score 2):

I do something like this in a few places in my codebase. You need an upload file wrapper, and you need another thread or a greenthread - I'm using eventlet for fake threading in my instance. Call `requests.put`, which will block on `read()` on your file-like object wrapper. The thread you call `put` in will block waiting, so you need to do the receiving in another.

Sorry for not posting code, I just saw this when I was zipping through. I hope this is enough to help, if not maybe I can edit and add more later.

Comment: Yeah, if you could give an example with using a fake thread, that would be awesome. The current solutions require me to either dive into the horrid depths of httplib (scary) or to implement my own threading layer (scarier).

Answer (score 1):

Requests actually supports multipart encoded requests with the `files` parameter:

[Multipart POST example in the official documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
r.text
{
  ...
  "files": {
    "file": "<censored...binary...data>"
  },
  ...
}
```

You can create your own file-like streaming object if you like, too, but you cannot mix a stream and files in the same request.

A simple case that might work for you would be to open the file and return a chunking, generator-based reader:

```
def read_as_gen(filename, chunksize=-1): # -1 defaults to read the file to the end, like a regular .read()
    with open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunksize)
            if len(chunk) > 0:
                yield chunk
            else:
                raise StopIteration

# Now that we can read the file as a generator with a chunksize, give it to the files parameter
files = {'file': read_as_gen(filename, 64*1024)}

# ... post as normal.
```

But if you had to block the chunking on something else, like another network buffer, you could handle that in the same manner:

```
def read_buffer_as_gen(buffer_params, chunksize=-1): # -1 defaults to read the file to the end, like a regular .read()
    with buffer_open(*buffer_params) as buf: # some function to open up your buffer
    # you could also just pass in the buffer itself and skip the `with` block
        while True:
            chunk = buf.read(chunksize)
            if len(chunk) > 0:
                yield chunk
            else:
                raise StopIteration
```

Comment: The problem with the approach that requests takes is that it "pulls" data from a file-like object. Internally, it essentially looks and sees if the object you pass is file-like, then iterates over that file, blocking until it has finished sending the file. The problem is that I need to _push_ to the request via a `write()` method. I'll update my question.

Comment: I've just updated the question with a better example of my use-case.

Comment: @TKKocheran gotcha. In that case I don't think `Requests` is able to solve that problem.

Answer (score -2):

This may help

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request(uri, data=data)
request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT' # or 'DELETE'
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: I don't think that you understand the question. I need to send data with a PUT request, not with a multipart POST.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding that.

Comment: import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request(uri, data=data)
request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT' # or 'DELETE'
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
this may be help/